# Multidimensional Array To Mysql Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

A little help how can I create an input query using this array? Or how 
   can I pass it in the table? my table layout sample is this:

sales_table

```
 id   |   product_name   |   price   |   qty   |   subtotal
```

This is derived from the var_dump() function.
Here is my code in array

```
//array code from unserialized function
    $products = unserialize($this->session->userdata('product_list'));

//This is the output.
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [product_name] => NOKIA 5110
            [product_desc] => Cellphone
            [product_price] => 500.00
            [product_qty] => 1
            [product_amount] => 500
            [product_code] => NOKI2012-84353
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [product_name] => HP IPAQ RW6828
            [product_desc] => Cellphone
            [product_price] => 1500.00
            [product_qty] => 1
            [product_amount] => 1500
            [product_code] => HP I2012-08386
        )
)
```

Comment: how are you getting that `product_list`?

Answer (score 0):

Make a method for inserting with a foreach loop that will iterate all of your products and insert them one by one

```
foreach($products as $p) {
    $data = array(
        'product_name' => $p['product_name'],
        'price' => $p['product_price'],
        'qty' => $p['product_qty'],
        'subtotal' => 1, // what do you want here?
    );

    $data2 = array(
        'product_stuff' => $p['product_code'],
        'product_stuffo' => 100 * $p['product_amount'], // anything you want
    );


    $this->db->insert('products', $data);
    $this->db->insert('sales_line', $data2);
}
```

You might want to make this code support transactions later.

Comment: Subtotal is in my session variable i dont have a problem with that. Other thing is i want to store it in two separate tables the other one is sales_line table